# How to dynamically count no. of selected radio buttons and show them inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've several radio buttons on my page, what i want is every time a button is checked or unchecked, it should be dynamically displayed on the web page.

```html
<div>
<h1>first part</h1>
 <input type ="radio" name="hope1" value="1">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope2" value="2">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope3" value="3">
<h2>second part</h2>
 <input type ="radio" name="hope1" value="4">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope2" value="5">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope3" value="6">
</div>

<div>
<h1> the no. of checkboxes selected are:"it should be displayed here"</h1> 
</div>
```

I am really new to javascript, please provide some solution.

Comment: nothing yet, i am new to jscript @abagshaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set an event listener on inputs for change event. give an id to `h1` that you want to change and set its text using `.text()`. `$('input[type="radio"]:checked').length` will give number of checked radio buttons. something like this:

```js
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
 $('#result').text("the no. of checkboxes selected are: " + $('input[type="radio"]:checked').length);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
<h1>first part</h1>
 <input type ="radio" name="hope1" value="">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope2" value="">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope3" value="">
<h2>second part</h2>
 <input type ="radio" name="hope1" value="">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope2" value="">
 <input type ="radio" name="hope3" value="">
</div>

<div>
<h1 id='result'> the no. of checkboxes selected are:"it should be displayed here"</h1> 
</div>
```